# Cash on delivery payment method should visible only for some zip codes magento module

Tags: magento-1.9, cash-on-delivery

How to make magento module for Cash on delivery payment method should visible only for **some zip codes/pin codes** and it can be **check in product page** also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for view page : http://www.nextbits.eu/check-delivery-availability-magento-extension.html

for checkout page , All you need is to edit the file `/app/code/local/Mage/Payment/Model/Method`/Cashondelivery.php

```
public function getInstructions()
        {
            return trim($this->getConfigData('instructions'));
        }

        public function isAvailable($quote = null)
    {
        if ($quote) {

            // Here is the list of restricted Zip Codes
            $restrictedZips = array(
    '641004'
    ,'641006'


    );

            $address = $quote->isVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();
            $customerZip = $address->getPostcode();

            if (!in_array($customerZip, $restrictedZips)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return parent::isAvailable($quote);
    }
    }
```

Comment: It didn't worked

Comment: @vithalreddy for both checkout page & view page, it did't worlked ?

Comment: It worked in view page but not in checkout page

Comment: strange, it worked for me.

Comment: did you added zip codes in the above code i posted ?

Comment: yes sir but its not showing in fronted page

Comment: are you telling other than the zip codes you added, those zip codes are also allowing for COD ?

Comment: Hey man i found the solution better than this.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you.

Comment: For view page it only works for base theme if change to other custom theme it is not working in mage v1.9.2.4

Comment: @BabyinMagento: Thanks for your code see this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190045/magento-1-9-3-2-coupon-code-active-remove-cash-on-delivery/190083#190083